# How to prevent Firefox toolbar to show on mouse hover in Full Screen Mode?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I am a big fan of **Full Screen Mode**. Single <kbd>F11</kbd> hit and you have a clean view with no menus, toolbars, etc.

However, I find it quite annoying when you accidentally hover the mouse to the top and all the toolbars show up again and resize the page content,forcing you to wait until they hides again.

I have seen couple of Kiosk mode add-ons which is a brute force solution. I don't want any other feature to be disabled or my web-history and passwords deleted upon closing. Only to disable an auto show of toolbars when you hover the mouse to the top edge of the scree. 
In my search I only found a single add-on called [FF Fullscreen](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/FF_Fullscreen/?src=search) which claims that

> This also removes the small border at the top of the fullscreen window that Firefox uses to give the user a way to auto-show the collapsed toolbar on mouse-over.

which in my case it did not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you need a user defined cascading style sheet (CSS):

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); 

#fullscr-toggler { display:none!important; }
```

For details see [Mozila Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1092572)

Comment: to be able to use userChrome.css nowdays, you have to set to true : toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets . See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1325862